# RSEI calculation Error in GEE (Incompatible number of bands in the mask)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, pca

I am trying to do Remote Sensing Ecological Index (RSEI) in GEE but I get this type of error. The code is also attached here.

> Layer 5: Layer error: Image.mask: Incompatible number of bands in the mask image: 4. Expected 1.

```
//NDVI
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA").filterBounds(roi)
.filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-12-10')
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 1).median().clip(roi);
var ndvi = L8.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);
Map.centerObject(roi, 7)

//wetness
var wetness = L8.expression(
  '0.151 * B2 + 0.197 * B3 + 0.328 * B4 - 0.340 * B5 - 0.711 * B6 - 0.457 * B7',
  {
    'B2': L8.select('B2'),
    'B3': L8.select('B3'),
    'B4': L8.select('B4'),
    'B5': L8.select('B5'),
    'B6': L8.select('B6'),
    'B7': L8.select('B7')
  }
).rename('wetness');



var ibi = L8.expression(
  '(2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR)) - (NIR / (NIR + Red)) - (Green / (Green + SWIR1)) / ' +
  '((2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR)) + (NIR / (NIR + Red)) + (Green / (Green + SWIR1)))',
  {
    'SWIR1': L8.select('B6'),
    'NIR': L8.select('B5'),
    'Red': L8.select('B4'),
    'Green': L8.select('B3')
  }
).rename('ibi');

// Calculate the Spectral Index (SI)
var spectralIndex = L8.expression(
  '((SWIR1 + Red) - (NIR + Blue))/((SWIR1 + Red) + (NIR + Blue))',
  {
    'SWIR1': L8.select('B6'),
    'Red': L8.select('B4'),
    'NIR': L8.select('B5'),
    'Blue': L8.select('B2')
  }
).rename('spectralIndex');


// Calculate the Normalized Difference Bareness-Snow Index(NDBSI)
var ndbsi = ee.Image(ibi.add(spectralIndex).divide(2)).rename('ndbsi');

// Define visualization parameters for NDBSI
var ndbsiVis = {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']
};
////
////LST////

var thermal= L8.select('B10');


//  min and max of NDVI
{
var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'min');


var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'max')
}

//fractional vegetation
{
var fv =(ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV'); 
print(fv, 'fv');

}
//Emissivity

var a= ee.Number(0.004);
var b= ee.Number(0.986);
var EM=fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');



//LST 

var LST = L8.expression(
'(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
 'Tb': L8.select('B10'),
'Ep': EM.select('EMM')
}).rename('LST');

////Normalize Index
///NDVI
{
var ndvi_min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(ndvi_min, 'ndvi_min');


var ndvi_max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(ndvi_max, 'ndvi_max')
}

//wetness
{
var wetness_min = ee.Number(wetness.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(wetness_min, 'wetness_min');


var wetness_max = ee.Number(wetness.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(wetness_max, 'wetness_max')
}

////NDBSI
{
var ndbsi_min = ee.Number(ndbsi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(ndbsi_min, 'ndbsi_min');


var ndbsi_max = ee.Number(ndbsi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(ndbsi_max, 'ndbsi_max')
}


///LST

{
var LST_min = ee.Number(LST.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(LST_min, 'lst_min');


var LST_max = ee.Number(LST.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: roi,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(LST_max, 'LST_max')
}



///NDVI
// Normalize NDVI, wetness, NDBSI & LST values
var normalizedNDVI = ndvi.subtract(ndvi_min).divide(ndvi_max.subtract(ndvi_min)).rename('normalized_ndvi');
var normalizedWetness = wetness.subtract(wetness_min).divide(wetness_max.subtract(wetness_min)).rename('normalized_wetness');
var normalizedNDBSI = ndbsi.subtract(ndbsi_min).divide(ndbsi_max.subtract(ndbsi_min)).rename('normalized_NDBSI');
var normalizedLST = LST.subtract(LST_min).divide(LST_max.subtract(LST_min)).rename('normalized_LST');

Map.addLayer(normalizedNDVI, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']}, 'Normalized NDVI');
Map.addLayer(normalizedWetness, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']}, 'normalized Wetness');
Map.addLayer(normalizedNDBSI, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']}, 'normalized NDBSI');
Map.addLayer(normalizedLST, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['green', 'red', 'blue']}, 'normalized LST');


var test = normalizedNDVI.addBands(normalizedWetness).addBands(normalizedNDBSI).addBands(normalizedLST);



//print('============================================> PCA ')
// get pca
function pca_model(image){
  
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
 // print('bandNames',bandNames)
    var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry:roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13});
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  //print(means);
  var centered = image.subtract(means); // get the de-mean value
  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
  var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
  return seq.map(function(b) {
    return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
  })};
  var arrays = centered.toArray(); // centerise and image to array
  var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(), // get the cov matrix
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  //print(covar);
  var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));
  var eigens = covarArray.eigen(); // get the vector
  // print('eigens',eigens);
  // var eigens_list = ee.List(eigens); // convert to the array
  
  // print(eigens_array.transpose(),'eigens_array');
  var eigens_img = ee.Image(eigens).rename('eigien');
  
  var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
  // print(eigenValues,'eigen value');
  var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
  // print(eigenVectors,'eigen vector');
  var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1); // to single image, contain 4 values
  // print(arrayImage);
  // Map.addLayer(arrayImage);
  var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage); // get the final results
  var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
    .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);
  // print(sdImage);
  // Map.addLayer(sdImage);

 // eigenvalue
  var eigenValues1 = ee.List(eigenValues.toList().get(0)).get(0);
  var eigenValues2 = ee.List(eigenValues.toList().get(1)).get(0);
  var eigenValues3 = ee.List(eigenValues.toList().get(2)).get(0);
  var eigenValues4 = ee.List(eigenValues.toList().get(3)).get(0);
  // var eigenValues5 = ee.List(eigenValues.toList().get(4)).get(0);
  var flag=ee.Array([1,1,-1,-1])
  var eigenVectors=ee.Array([ee.Array(eigenVectors.toList().get(0)).abs().multiply(flag).toList(),
                  eigenVectors.toList().get(1),
                  eigenVectors.toList().get(2),
                  eigenVectors.toList().get(3)])
  // var eigenVectors=ee.Array([ee.Array(eigenVectors.toList().get(0)).multiply(-1).toList(),
  //               eigenVectors.toList().get(1),
  //               eigenVectors.toList().get(2),
  //               eigenVectors.toList().get(3)])

  var eigen_sum=eigenValues.toList().flatten().reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
  var contribution_rate=eigenValues.divide(eigen_sum)
  
  // print('covarArray',covarArray)
  // print('eigenVectors',eigenVectors)
  // print('eigenValues',eigenValues)
  // print('contribution_rate',contribution_rate)
  
  // eigenvector
  var pca1 = principalComponents.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')]).divide(sdImage).select(0);
  var pca2 = principalComponents.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')]).select(1);
  var pca3 = principalComponents.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')]).select(2);
  var pca4 = principalComponents.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')]).select(3);
  
  
  //var result = pca1.updateMask(mndwi_mask);
var result = pca1.mask(image.mask())
  return result;
  // return principalComponents
  //   .arrayProject([0])
  //   .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
  //   .addBands(eigens_img.select('eigien'));
    // .divide(sdImage);
}
var pca1 = pca_model(test);//test is a Image including NDVI,WET,NDBSI,and LST bands
RSEI=ee.Image.constant(1).clip(roi).subtract(pca1) ;

Map.addLayer(RSEI)
```

Comment: In Earth Engine, each band has its own mask. When you try to mask a single-band image with a multi-band image, Earth Engine doesn't know which mask to use. As explained in the error, you're providing 4 mask bands when it's expecting 1. To fix that you'll need to select a single band from your image before applying the mask.